# XF binding data from a popuppage to a contentpage through xaml

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a popup page in my application which includes some checkboxes, and I also have a ContentPage in my MainPage which contains some stacklayouts, I want to bind the IsVisible Property of my stacklayout to the IsChecked property of my checkbox (which is in another page), but i don't know how to do it, can anybody please help?
I've tried this, but it doesn't work

here's the code in my popup page:

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="60">
            <local:Checkbox x:Name="va1Checkbox"  Text="VA1"/>
            <local:Checkbox x:Name="va2Checkbox" Text="VA2"/>             
        </StackLayout>
```

and this is the piece of code i have in my MainPage:

```
      <StackLayout   IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference 
                                               va1Checkbox},Path=IsChecked}">

      </StackLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="60">
    <local:Checkbox x:Name="va1Checkbox"  Text="VA1"/>
    <local:Checkbox x:Name="va2Checkbox" Text="VA2"/>             
</StackLayout>
```

I believe your popup represents some kind of settings based on which you control your `StackLayout` in Main Page.

If this is the case, there are two possible solutions.

1. Create a separate class which is binding for both checkbox and layout. You can use this either with MVVM or without it.
2. Value Passing: open popup from Main Page and register to its close event. When popup is closed you can use its checkbox's value to enable/disable the layout.

In your Popup.xaml.cs :

create an event action

```
public event Action<Popup> OnClose;
```

I believe you will have a way to close it. I don't know you are closing it so I will just use `OnBackButtonPressed()` here:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    OnClose?.Invoke(this);
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

In your MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
private void OpenPopup()
{
    var popup = new PopupPage();
    popup.OnClose += OnPopupClosed;
}

void OnPopupClosed(Popup popup)
{
    yourStackLayout.IsVisible = popup.va1Checkbox.Value;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can pass custom data class instead of popup object:

```
public class PopupData
{
    public bool va1CheckboxValue;
    public bool va1CheckboxValue;
    // other data which you need to access in other page.
}
```

then

```
public event Action<PopupData> OnClose;
```

and

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    PopupData data = new PopupData() { va1CheckboxValue = va1Checkbox.Value; }
    OnClose?.Invoke(data);
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

and in main page:

```
void OnPopupClosed(PopupData data)
{
    yourStackLayout.IsVisible = data.va1CheckboxValue;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much i tried this but there is one problem, when i write this line of code: yourStackLayout.IsVisible = popup.va1Checkbox.Value; i get this error: va1Checkbox is inaccessible due to its protection level, i have set x:FileModifier ti public, but i'm still getting this error, any idea about this problem?

Comment: I am not certain about this but I think FileModifier originally for WinRT and not Xamarin. You should be able to work around by passing a data object in callback. Check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you, i'ii give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well XAML and MVVM, but I think you can pass MainPage's ViewModel to Popup... if you change MainPage's ViewModel properties in Popup I think these changes will reflect also to MainPage's binded controls.

If you are not using MVVM (you should...), I think you have to pass a reference to properties used in MainPage to Popup... in this way, Popup can change MainPage's properties and its UI could change

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using MVVM, I just want to do a simple binding between two seperate pages

Comment: how can I pass a reference to properties used in MainPage to Popup through XAML? Sorry I am new to xamarin

Comment: Not through XAML. I think you can pass MainPage's references through Popup constructor and use it in xaml. MainPage should have a checkbox1 property that is bined to StackLayout's IsVisible Property. Pass this checkbox1 property to Popup using Popup's constructor and modify it when in Popup va1Checkbox changes